# Trying to work out % MYSQL, Seperate statements work ok

Tags: mysql, sum, rounding, percentage, divide

I have a mysql select statement which works fine:

```
SELECT advisor AS advisor, team,        
SUM(time) -  SUM(CASE WHEN `queue` like '%Oth%' THEN time END) as case_time,
Count(distinct date) * 450 - SUM(CASE WHEN `queue` like '%Oth%' THEN time END) as time_av
FROM shift_report 
WHERE `team` = 1 and `date`>'20160701' group by `advisor` order by `advisor` ASC
```

I want to divide case_time by time_av and * 100 to get the percentage of 'actual_time'

I tried this but it did not work:

```
round(SUM(time) -  SUM(CASE WHEN `queue` like '%Oth%' THEN time END) / 
Count(distinct date) * 450 - SUM(CASE WHEN `queue` like '%Oth%' THEN time END) * 100, 2)
```

Any ideas??

Comment: it didn't work means it's giving error or showing nothing?. Can you provide above SQL sample result?

Comment: If I manually divide the result from case_time by the result from time_av and * by 100 I get the answer I need.

Comment: Please try to replace  Count(distinct date) with ( Select count( distinct date ) from shift_report as s where s.advisor = shift_report.advisor) as total_count

Comment: The query works, but the result is not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

round( (SUM(time) - SUM(CASE WHEN queue like '%Oth%' THEN time END))/ (Count(distinct date) * 450 - SUM(CASE WHEN queue like '%Oth%' THEN time END)) * 100, 2) as result

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed parenthesis. Modified SQL please run and see.

```
    select  round( (SUM(time) - SUM(CASE WHEN queue like '%Oth%' THEN time END))/ 
(Count(distinct date) * 450 - SUM(CASE WHEN queue like '%Oth%' THEN time END) * 
100), 2) as result FROM shift_report WHERE team = 1 and date>'20160701'
```

Comment: I ran this and get error 1241 : Operand should contain 1 column

Comment: Same result again, the query does't run and gives 1241 error. If I seperate the queries i.e. case_time and time_av they both give correct results back. It only returns incorrect values when I tried to divide case_time by time_av

Comment: sorry, I modified my answer. can you run once again

Comment: The query runs this time, the results are incorrect though, mostly -0. Doing the sum manually these should all be between 50-100 (%)

Comment: I've worked it out... round( (SUM(time) - SUM(CASE WHEN queue like '%Oth%' THEN time END))/ 
(Count(distinct date) * 450 - SUM(CASE WHEN queue like '%Oth%' THEN time END)) * 100, 2) as result

Comment: Thanks for your help Venkatesh Panabaka, got me on the right track :-)